# When should a question be moved to SoftwareEngineering.SE?

Tags: support, migration, software-engineering-se

Recently, I came across this question: [How Many Objects Inside of a Class is too Many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551267/how-many-objects-inside-of-a-class-is-too-many).

This is a question about OO design, something that I feel is covered under "Design patterns" at SoftwareEngineering.SE. However, it could just as well remain at SO, because it is a programming question ("matters that are unique to the programming profession"), but that could stop almost any question from being migrated.

Bottom line: how can you decide whether or not a question should be migrated to SoftwareEngineering.SE?

Comment: Hm, I thought this was a duplicate, but maybe I was just thinking of [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange), which is merely similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The correct action was not to edit and bump this, but rather, to close it. Please consider the questions you edit carefully, especially if they are 6 years old with a handful of views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## When it doesn't belong in the toilet bowl instead.

[Here's the rules to help you avoid said toilet bowl:](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)

All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. How do we define that? Constructive subjective questions …

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
- tend to have long, not short, answers.
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
- invite sharing experiences over opinions.
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
- are more than just mindless social fun.